Automatically extract relevant headers belonging to a static library
I'm building a static library and want to automatically deploy header files next to the library that are required for the use of the library.
I don't want to deploy headers that are not to be used from outside the library.
For functions that are working already. I compile with gcc -fvisibility=hidden and add __attribute__((visibility ("protected"))) to functions that need to be visible from outside the library ("default" would also work). For deployment, I use objcopy --localize-hidden lib.a and nm --extern-only --defined-only lib.a to automatically extract the headers with those functions.
But: I also need some headers that just have structs or enums that need to be visible. I tried adding __attribute__((visibility ("protected"))) as well, but the above method does not work, they are not listed by nm. Static variables on the other hand get listed. But I'm not interested in them.
I then tried objdump --dwarf=info lib.a and found the structs and enums, but I could not find a difference between protected/default and hidden ones. I read about DW_AT_visibility but that attribute was not listed. Is there any way to get that information compiled into the library. Or if it is already in there: how do I extract it from the library?
The next hurdle will be header files that just include other header files according to set preprocessor defines. Or that just inhabit macros. How could it be possible to extract those header files automatically? Is there something similar to the described function workflow?
Alternatively, they need to be deployed manually. Or have a special naming scheme, e.g. *_public.h. But that is like a compromise solution and error-prone.
Note: There are more GCC options like g2 already active. I have no makefile.
I looked also in some tools like pahole but Windows is a requirement and as I understand it, pahole would be no help with that issue anyway. I tried to get LLVM to the help, but the project CPU is not known to the tools. It is a TriCore and the compiler supplies the listed tools (tricore-gcc.exe, tricore-nm.exe v4.6.* etc.) but for simplicity I just wrote GCC.

You need to create an installer which packages all the files you want to distribute.

The current situation is to list all the files that need to be deployed, yes. But I want to get rid of the manual process and automate that. Or how does the packaging of the installer work? Note: I do not just want all header files. Just the ones that need public access.
Later the library and the header files will be included in multiple projects that rely on the library.

You could split the public, protected, and private headers into separate directories. Only the contents of the public and protected header directories should be deployed. You could make the protected header directory be a subdirectory of the public header directory, and document that they are only intended to be included indirectly from the public headers.
